# Phase transition in 2+1D QED for $\theta =\pi$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, quantum-electrodynamics, phase-transition, topology

QED in 1+1 dimensions with a massive fermion, called the [massive Schwinger model](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491676902803), has a phase transition at $\theta=\pi$ for some finite critical mass $m_c$. Equivalently, one can say that the Schwinger model has a phase transition at $\theta=0$ and $-m_c$ because a shift of $m\to -m$ corresponds to a shift of $\theta\to\theta +\pi$ due to the [axial anomaly](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/3anom.pdf), which appears in the derivative of the fermionic axial-vector current.

Is there something analogous happening for QED in 2+1 dimensions with a massive fermion? I know that the [Chern-Simons term in 2+1D QED](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9501280.pdf) is analogous to the $\theta$-term in 1+1D QED. However, according to [Redlich (1984)](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.2366), in 2+1D we only have an anomaly in the fermionic vector current, not in the derivative of the axial-vector current. Therefore, I'm wondering:

(1) Do we have the correspondence of $m\to -m$ and $\theta\to\theta +\pi$ in 2+1D QED?

(2) Do we get a phase transition for $\theta=\pi$ and some finite critical mass $m_c$ in 2+1D QED?

(3) If so, is this phase transition also present for $\theta=0$ (i.e., no Chern-Simons term) and a negative critical mass $-m_c$?

Comment: What do you mean? There is no continuous theta parameter in 2+1d.

Comment: I mean the Chern-Simons coefficient that's called theta in Eq. (1) of the [reference above](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9501280.pdf). I think it can take continuous values, see, e.g., Figs. 5 and 6a in that paper. And even without the theta parameter, I'm wondering whether there could be a phase transition for some $-m_c$.